# using debug mode through wireless, can't change it back

Tags: android, adb

So i figured out to debug in elclipse on my android device through wifi using the following commands:

adb tcpip 5555
adb connect "ip address of device":5555

now I can't get it back to usb mode. It should be done by simply calling:

adb usb

but I get the error

error: device not found

I've tried it with the device plugged in and no luck. I've also noticed that my motorola device manager doesn't come up, and the device itself (Droid RAZR) doesn't sense being connected to the computer (like giving me the option of changing the usb mode) it only charges now. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just make sure it is all running through wifi, then run adb usb and voila! Stumped me for a bit so I hope it helps someone out there. Remember to turn it back to usb mode before you leave your wifi access otherwise you can't use usb!